# ORA-29400: data cartridge error KUP-04018: partial record at end of file - Only for aggregate functions

Tags: oracle, external

I am facing the error - **"ORA-29400: data cartridge error KUP-04018: partial record at end of file" **for an external table. I am able to **select **the table, but while performing any aggregate functions such as group by, count etc on the external table, it throws this error.

The file is fixed width and therefore tried to modify the "RECORDS FIXED " to "RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE" and it worked even for aggregate functions. However, would like to know the root cause why it is not working for aggregate functions if its not modified as above. Please let me know any inputs/reasons. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you `select *` from the external table, did you fetch all the records from the table? I suspect you didn't. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784771/external-tables-partial-record-at-end-of-file-error-when-using-fixed) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, not all records were getting fetched. I pressed enter and thus a new line created in the file and then when i reran with the "records fixed" it worked fine.